# cakephp jquery onchange event not working

Tags: jquery, cakephp

when i click onchange event jquery alert is not working. i write the document.ready function in default.ctp.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

        $("#office_type_id").onchange(function() {   
            alert("Thanks for clicking.");
        });

    </script>

<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Office');
echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Form->input('district');
echo $this->Form->input('address');

echo $this->Form->input('office_type', array('type' => 'select', 'id' =>'office_type_id','options' => $settings1,'empty'   => false));
echo $this->Form->end('Save');
?>
```

Comment: Change it to `$("#office_type_id").on('change', function() {`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#office_type_id").on('change',function() {   
        alert("Thanks for clicking.");
    });
```

jquery onchange funciton change. there is no onchange function.